# Angular Model Change not Applying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div on which I have applied the [textangular](http://textangular.com/) directive

```
<div text-angular ng-model="htmlContent" ng-change="processChange()"
```

Then I added the processChange function to the scope

```
function demoController($scope) {
        $scope.htmlContent = '<h2>شاہ مکھی کاتب</h2><p>....';
        $scope.processChange = function () {
            $scope.htmlContent = $scope.htmlContent.replace('b', 'ب');
            $scope.apply();
        };
    };
```

Now, even though I'm calling apply(), the replacement does not bind back to the display, until I loose focus from the div. While I'm still typing, it does not apply. What must I do for the model change to immediately reflect back, as the user is still typing?

I'm trying to allow conversion of characters from one language to another, without the user having the need to install its specific keyboard.

Update: Plunker script http://plnkr.co/edit/HSPxDBoPjzNNeaKoKEtY?p=preview

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Try to change htmlContent to object.htmlContent, $scope.htmlContent => $scope.object.htmlContent

Comment: Here is the script
http://plnkr.co/edit/HSPxDBoPjzNNeaKoKEtY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "ng-keyup" instead of the "ng-change" event listener. Also do read up on how to pass the $event to ng-keyup listener to properly use it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-click instead of ng-change

```
<div text-angular ng-model="htmlContent" ng-click="processChange()">
{{htmlContent}}
</div>
```